# Get a substring from a string with a unique identifier with java

Tags: java, java-8, substring

I have a string:

```
String example = "<UserGroup:groupName> , <RULE: ruleName>";
```

I would like to extract groupName and ruleName  from this, i.e. the substring would be

> String userGroup = groupName; String rule = ruleName;

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: Your questions is a little unclear—are you parsing specifically for `userGroup` and `rule`, or are you parsing generally for anything in the format `<VariableName:Value>`? Do you have have any code that you've tried that you're having an issue with?

Comment: you are right format  is <VariableName:Value>, so here i have 2 VariableNames

Comment: You should learn [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and show some attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the input string into individual terms based on where the commas fall, and feed those into a lookup map containing the keys and values. Splitting based on the `:` allows you to separate the keys from the values.

Then you simply lookup any needed values in the map:

```
String input = "<UserGroup:groupName> , <RULE: ruleName>";

Map<String, String> keyVals = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                                    .filter(s -> s.contains(":"))
                                    .map(s -> s.trim())
                                    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("<|>", ""))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        s -> s.split(":")[0].toLowerCase().trim(),
                                        s -> s.split(":")[1].trim()
                                    ));
String userGroup = keyVals.get("usergroup");
String rule = keyVals.get("rule");
```

Comment: That results in `userGroup = null` and `rule = null`

Comment: yes it's  result is null

Comment: Oops, forgot to strip the angle brackets out. Works correctly now!

Comment: Don't do the split twice, and combine the map calls: `map(s -> s.replaceAll("[<>]", "").trim().split(":"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

1. Split with any spaces before and after the comma: `\s*,\s*`
2. Split with any spaces before and after the colon: `<(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)>`.

Here the code

```
    String input = "<UserGroup:groupName> , <RULE: ruleName> , <Name: Value>";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+)>");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s*,\\s*")).forEach(part -> {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(part);
        if (matcher.find())
            map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    });

    System.out.println("UserGroup: " + map.get("groupName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<UserGroup:groupName> , <RULE: ruleName>";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
        String[] elements = new String[2];
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            elements[i] = matcher.group(1);
            i++;
        }

        String userGroup = elements[0].substring(elements[0].indexOf(":") + 1, elements[0].length()).trim();
        String rule = elements[1].substring(elements[1].indexOf(":") + 1, elements[1].length()).trim();

        System.out.println(userGroup + " " + rule);

    }

}
```

Output :

```
groupName ruleName
```